# How to export database? MySql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am new at databases. I have table and and I need to export it and save its structure. I'm using MySql Workbench. It is my first task and I have no idea and know just few things about databases.

Comment: Google it. You will get a million results

Comment: Bing it too, just to be safe.

Comment: I tried, but I am so confused. I found something about exporting, but I just need to be sure

Comment: .sql file is exported database? how to save database structure for downloading it?

Comment: It has both the DDL and the DML in it.  You should be safe.  If you are concerned about it, open the file and look for create table statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unprecise. What exactly do you want to export? The table structure + data for later restore (if so use a dump) or just the table data in a common format like CSV for further processing (if so use the table data export wizard).

A dump is what is usually used to store SQL data + structure in text files (conventionally tagged with an .sql extension). These contain **Data Definition Language** (DDL) constructs which define the meta data (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`) as well as **Data Manipulation Language** (DML) commands to manage the content (e.g. `INSERT` or `DELETE`). This structure serves well for copying content between servers and such, as it is what a database server speaks natively. In MySQL Workbench you can import and export such dumps via the Management tab -> Data Import/Restore:

[image]

For importing and exporting data via a common file format like CSV or JSON, use the table data import/export feature, reachable via the context menu for a given table:

[image]

this does however not preserve the structure of the table in a manner which would allow to recreate it automatically (like SQL statements do).